# RKMappingresult returning different result in 64-bit iphones with restkit

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, restkit, rkobjectmapping

I have a strange problem with `Restkit`. I'm doing the following:

```
-(void)doLogin:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)password OnCompletion:(myCompletion) compblock{
    Mapper *mapper = [Mapper new];
    RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[OffitelDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
    NSLog(@"store is %@",store);
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [mapper mapLogin];
    NSString *deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"deviceToken"];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"company-user/login/%@?email=%@&pwd=%@&ios_id=%@",apikey,email,password,deviceToken];
    NSURLRequest *request = [objectManager requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:urlString parameters:nil];
    RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request managedObjectContext:context success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL success = [context  save:&error];
        if (!success) RKLogWarning(@"Failed saving managed object context: %@", error);
        Data *data2 = [mappingResult.array objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"MAPPING RESULT 0 = %@",[mappingResult.array objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSLog(@"data status is %@",data2.webstatus);
        int value = [data2.webstatus intValue];
        if (value == 200){
            Person  *personObject = [mappingResult.array objectAtIndex:2];
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",personObject.cu_first_name,personObject.cu_last_name];
            NSDictionary *dictUser = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:personObject.cu_id,@"personId",personObject.company.c_id,@"companyId",name,@"personName",personObject.cu_status_id,@"statusId", nil];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:dictUser forKey:@"user"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"loggedIn"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            compblock(YES);
        }else{
            //show validation
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
        }
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"ERROR");
    }];
    [objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

En this is my mapping

```
-(RKObjectManager *)mapLogin{

    RKObjectMapping* dataMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Data class]];
    [dataMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                      @"status": @"webstatus",
                                                      @"message": @"message",
                                                      @"text": @"text"
                                                      }];
    RKEntityMapping* personMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    personMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"cu_id"] ;
    [personMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"cu_id":              @"cu_id",
                                                        @"cu_status_id":       @"cu_status_id",
                                                        @"cu_company_id":      @"cu_company_id",
                                                        @"cu_function_id":     @"cu_function_id",
                                                        @"cu_department_id":   @"cu_department_id",
                                                        @"cu_email":           @"cu_email",
                                                        @"cu_first_name":      @"cu_first_name",
                                                        @"cu_last_name":       @"cu_last_name",
                                                        @"cu_phone_intern":    @"cu_phone_intern",
                                                        @"cu_mobile_phone":    @"cu_mobile_phone",
                                                        @"cu_street":          @"cu_street",
                                                        @"cu_number":          @"cu_number",
                                                        @"cu_bus":             @"cu_bus",
                                                        @"cu_postalcode":      @"cu_postalcode",
                                                        @"cu_location":        @"cu_location",
                                                        @"cu_country":         @"cu_country",
                                                        @"cu_birthdate":       @"cu_birthdate",
                                                        @"cu_picture":         @"cu_picture",
                                                        @"cu_comment":         @"cu_comment",
                                                        @"cu_ison_reminder_email": @"cu_ison_reminder_email",
                                                        @"cu_ison_reminder_app":   @"cu_ison_reminder_app",
                                                        @"cu_ison_reminder_web":   @"cu_ison_reminder_web",
                                                        @"cu_first_use":       @"cu_first_use"
                                                        }];
    RKEntityMapping* functionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Function" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    functionMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"cf_id"] ;
    [functionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                          @"cf_id": @"cf_id",
                                                          @"cf_name":@"cf_name"
                                                          }];
    RKEntityMapping* departmentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Department" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    departmentMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"cd_id"] ;
    [departmentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                            @"cd_id": @"cd_id",
                                                            @"cd_name":@"cd_name"
                                                            }];
    RKEntityMapping* companyMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    companyMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"c_id"] ;
    [companyMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                         @"c_id": @"c_id",
                                                         @"c_name":@"c_name",
                                                         @"c_phone":@"c_phone",
                                                         @"c_fax":@"c_fax",
                                                         @"c_website":@"c_website"
                                                         }];

    RKEntityMapping* statusMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Status" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    statusMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"cs_id"] ;
    [statusMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"cs_id": @"cs_id",
                                                        @"cs_company_id":@"cs_company_id",
                                                        @"cs_name":@"cs_name",
                                                        @"cs_default":@"cs_default",
                                                        @"cs_image":@"cs_image"
                                                        }];
    RKRelationshipMapping* relationFunctionMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"function"toKeyPath:@"function"withMapping:functionMapping];
    RKRelationshipMapping* relationDepartmentMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"department"toKeyPath:@"department"withMapping:departmentMapping];
    RKRelationshipMapping* relationCompanyMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"company"toKeyPath:@"company"withMapping:companyMapping];
    RKRelationshipMapping* relationStatusMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"statuses"toKeyPath:@"status"withMapping:statusMapping];

    [personMapping addPropertyMapping:relationFunctionMapping];
    [personMapping addPropertyMapping:relationDepartmentMapping];
    [personMapping addPropertyMapping:relationCompanyMapping];
    [companyMapping addPropertyMapping:relationStatusMapping];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:dataMapping
                                                                                       pathPattern:nil
                                                                                           keyPath:@"data"                                                                                       statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor2 = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:personMapping
                                                                                        pathPattern:nil
                                                                                            keyPath:@"data.user"
                                                                                        statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor3 = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:companyMapping
                                                                                        pathPattern:nil
                                                                                            keyPath:@"data.user.company"
                                                                                        statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
    NSArray *arrResponsDescriptor = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:responseDescriptor,responseDescriptor2,responseDescriptor3, nil];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:arrResponsDescriptor];
    return objectManager;
}
```

The strange this is that on most phones it all works correct but only on `64-bit devices` are going wrong.

When I look at this NSLog

```
NSLog(@"MAPPING RESULT 0 = %@",[mappingResult.array objectAtIndex:0]);
```

I see that in the `not-64-bit devices` it returns the `Data class` object. And thats oké. But in the `64-bit devices` it returns the `Company-object` and that's not ok !

Can somebody help me with this ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple response descriptors each with a `nil` path pattern, so they will always be applied to any response. RestKit does not guarantee the order in which they will be called. It also doesn't guarantee the order of the contents of `mappingResult.array`.

You should be using your key paths on the response descriptors to access the results of each descriptor. The `mappingResult` also offers you a dictionary (instead of array) where you can use the response descriptor key path to access the associated results. Use that to separate the `Data` results from the `Company` results.

Comment: oké but how does it come that it works on all devices but not on a 64-bit device ?

Comment: I can't say explicitly as a lot of code run between you making a request and getting a mapping result so knowing exactly which code runs in a different order is hard (and I haven't read 100% of that code). The point is that you should never have relied on the order...